# How to extract html content?I have a HTML page. How to extract the data inside a defined tags and print it in a o/p file.???

Tags: html, html-parsing, extract, jsoup

```
            <div class="message">In Arumbakkam - Opp to CMBT bustand is 1.5C/gr. Unless you are particular about the temple, may want to see Arumbakkam, as if you cross Pondamalle rd, you can go to Anna nagar, where, you can get all the extra caricular activities for kids. plus all high end reastaurants and shops</div>
```

I agree, Arumbakkam is a perfect location in between AnnaNagar and Vadapalani. Also it is in the junction of Poonamallee Road and IRR.

---------->the out put should be like this

In Arumbakkam - Opp to CMBT bustand is 1.5C/gr. Unless you are particular about the temple, may want to see Arumbakkam, as if you cross Pondamalle rd, you can go to Anna nagar, where, you can get all the extra caricular activities for kids. plus all high end reastaurants and shops

How to get this using Jsoup. help me a simple program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Elements content = Jsoup.connect(link).get().select("div#message");
```